# Derivation of conditional Gamma distribution

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, gibbs

I'm reading a paper and hoping to implement the authors particular version of a Gibbs sampler.  I can follow their description of the algorithm just fine... but I'm getting lost in the finer details when they derive their conditional distributions (I don't have a statistics background).

Here's some of the priors from their hierarchical model...
$$\mu \sim \mathcal{N}\left( 0, 1 \right),$$
$$\tau \sim \text{Gamma} \left( a, v \right),$$
$$\mu_u \sim \cal{N}\left( \mu, \tau^{-1} \right), $$
which then somehow results in this conditional density:
$$\tau|(\mu, \mu_1, \ldots, \mu_U) \sim \text{Gamma}\left(a + \frac{U}{2}, v + \frac{\sum^U_{u=1} (\mu_u - \mu)^2}{2}\right).$$

I can see they somehow incorporate the sample variance of previous esiotmates of $\mu_u$ into their prior $\tau$ to result in the conditional posterior... but I had trouble finding any online resources explaining exactly how this is done.

Would someone be able to walk me through the derivation of this conditional density?

I've tried to trim this down to only the relevant info for the question... so let me know if you think I left out any important details.

Referenced paper:

- [Rodrigues, G. S., Nott, D. J. and Sisson, S. A. (2020). Likelihood-free approximate Gibbs sampling. Stat Comput 30, 1057–1073.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-020-09933-x)

Comment: I think you'll find the relevant derivation [on the conjugate prior Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) specifically [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf)

Comment: lol, came here to say this. Specifically, you want [row five of this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution)

Comment: wow, great!  Thanks both, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RTbecard no worries, it's been one of my most-visited pages in the last year or so :)